# Get Name of Message registered by RegisterWindowMessage

Tags: sendmessage, windows-messages

I am debugging an old application, where the WndProc is overridden. There I got a message with ID=0xC1B0 which means, that this is a system wide unique message according to this [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx#app_defined).

As described by microsoft for the [`RegisterWindowMessage(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947(v=vs.85).aspx), the same string s the paramter results in the same message-id. So there is an unique link between the message-id and the parameter.

My question is now: Is there a possibility to get the parameter, if I have the message-id? If yes, this might help me to find the source of the message.

Comment: Favor Spy++, it shows the string.  Or use GetClipboardFormatName().

Comment: Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As found in the this [blog](http://linux.m2osw.com/recover-name-message-registered-registerwindowmessage) there is no direct way, but the function [`GetClipboardFormatName(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649040(v=vs.85).aspx) gives a work around for the problem.

I used it in the following way:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetClipboardFormatName(int format, StringBuilder lpszFormatName, int cchMaxCount);

public static string GetMessageName(int msg)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(256);
    GetClipboardFormatName(msg, sb, sb.Capacity);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```